# SharePoint 2013 Empty Project - Page Load

Tags: 2013, visual-web-part

I created a new SharePoint 2013 Empty Project in Visual Studio, I added visual web part. I want to write code at Page Load. But Page Load doesn't appear under my project. How to I find it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's inside username.ascx?

Comment: When I add new visual web part it created. I added under my questions @AtishDipongkor

Comment: While adding webpart `username` din't you got the `.vb` or `.c#` file along with `.ascx`?

Comment: That means problem is in your VS. code behind file is not generating properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried replicating your issue. For some reason the code behind file is not showing in the solution explorer.

Judging from your screenshot, the last line shows that the code behind file has been created. I found the code behind file by right clicking on the *.ascx file and then choosing "View Code."

Comment: When I choosing "View Code",  *.ascx.vb is opening. It should open *.ascx.cs. I like to choose the wrong type of project?

Comment: Choose a C# project then. You have chosen an vb project.